# Prolog recursion natural language generation

Tags: recursion, prolog

I am trying to call `trans(~P).` for instance and would like the output to be `Not P.`
Still new to Prolog.

```
trans(A, A).
trans(B, B).
trans(~, Not).
trans(~A) :- trans(~), trans(A).
```

Comment: By `Not P` do you mean an atom `'Not P'`? Or are you looking for a term, `not(P)`? Also note in Prolog anything starting with a capital letter not in quotes is a variable. So in `trans(~, Not).`, the `Not` is a variable.

Comment: Ideally an atom 'Not P' that would generate recursively from the two previous trans rules. The plan is to be able to generate a full sentence example trans(P v ~Q). would output 'P or not Q'

Comment: Would you recommend something like:
`trans('P','P').`
`trans('~', not).`

Comment: If you don't want `P` to be a variable, then, yes. But I think what I'd do is stick with lower case for your constant terms like `p` and `q`. It would be less cumbersome in Prolog. Rather than carry around the single quotes. And then use variables like `P` or `Q` when you want a variable. You might also want to look at the `op/3` directive, which would allow you to define things like `v` and `~` as operators. Then you could write `trans(p v ~q)` in Prolog and it would accept `p v ~q` as a term (you would still need to define predicates for `v/2` and `~/1`).

Comment: So,
`trans(p, p).
trans(q, q).
trans(r, r).
trans(s, s).
trans(~, not).
trans(~p) :- trans(~), trans(p).`

trans(p,M).
M = P.

Is what I wanted, however I still cant get trans(~p,M). working?

Comment: No, you just want one rule for atoms. You probably want something like `trans(P, P) :- atom(P).` since you are translating something to itself it's an atom, but not a term. So `p` is an atom, but `p v q` is not an atom.

Comment: I have also taken into account your op/3 suggestion and added that at the start to dictate precedence.

Comment: I've added a second atom rule so two variables can be used in rules such as ^ And, v Or.

`:- op(100,fy,~). 
:- op(150,xfy,^). 
:- op(200,xfy,v). 
:- op(250,xfy,=>).
:- op(300,xfy,<=>).

trans(P, P) :- atom(P).
trans(Q, Q) :- atom(Q).
trans(~, ~) :- atom(not).
trans(~P) :- trans(~), trans(P).
trans(P ^ Q) :- trans(P) and trans(Q).`

Comment: I can't seem to get the not rule to work. It's trying to get it recognised as a different symbol to prevent it falling into the first P atom rule.

Comment: You don't need both `trans(P, P) :- atom(P).` and `trans(Q, Q) :- atom(Q).` They say the exact same thing. I wouldn't try to `trans` the operators directly. You'll get an error because you're trying to use operators without operands. You'd want something like, `trans(~P) :- write('not '), trans(P).`

Comment: `?- trans(~p).
not 
false.

?- trans(~p,M).
false.`

that is after using the suggested trans(~P) line

Comment: Oops, sorry. Instead of `trans(P, P) :- atom(P).` use `trans(P) :- atom(P), write(P).` I'm assuming you want to write out the translation, not put the translation in a variable. Or is that true?

Comment: No you are correct, I wish to write out the translation.

Comment: Ok, that now works. Could I be rather cheeky and ask politely if you could explain why that works.

Comment: No worries. `trans(~p)` will write out the "not " and query `trans(p)`. That will catch the rule `trans(P) :- atom(P), write(P).` and `atom(p)` will succeed, so `write(P)` will write out `p`. Thus you get `not p`.

Comment: So, atom(P) is like a check measure to ensure that P is a single atom rather than a variable?

Comment: That's partially correct. It also makes sure it's not a term, like `p v q`. If it's a term, you want another predicate `trans(P v Q) :-...` to take care of that.

Comment: In case you're interested...

`trans(P) :- atom(P), write(P).
trans(~P) :- write('Not '), trans(P).

trans(~P ^ Q) :- trans(Q), write(' And '), trans(~P).
trans(~P v Q) :- trans(Q), write(' Or '), trans(~P).
trans(P ^ Q) :- trans(P), write(' And '), trans(Q).
trans(P v Q) :- trans(P), write(' Or '), trans(Q).
trans(P => Q) :- write('If '), trans(P), write(' Then '), trans(Q).
trans(P <=> Q) :- trans(P), write(' Only If '), trans(Q).`

A piece of my project is to take in any prop logic formula and express it in English. As you can see i've added a few more rules. Next problem is ambiguity.

Comment: I can't decide whether to write a predicate such as `trans((p v q) ^ r)` to catch as read as `p Or q followed by And r` or include brackets to it would be `(p or q) and r`
Opinions?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51690/discussion-between-chris-shanks-and-lurker)

Comment: @lurker So, is one of you going to write an answer and submit it?

Comment: @DanielLyons I wasn't totally sure I was taking it in a direction the OP ultimately needed to go, and hadn't concluded whether it was the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

Following along the lines of what I think you are asking:

```
% Define operators for input expressions

:- op(100,fy,~).
:- op(150,xfy,^). 
:- op(200,xfy,v). 
:- op(250,xfy,=>).
:- op(300,xfy,<=>).

% Define translators

trans(P) :- atom(P), write(P).

trans(P ^ Q) :-
    trans(P), write(' and '), trans(Q).
trans(P v Q) :-
    trans(P), write(' or '), trans(Q).
trans(~P) :-
    write('not '), trans(P).
trans(P => Q) :-
    write('if '), trans(P), write(' then '), trans(Q).
trans(P <=> Q) :-
    trans(P), write(' if and only if '), trans(Q).
```

And this would give:

```
| ?- trans((a ^ b) <=> (c v d)).
a and b if and only if c or d

yes
```

It would seem, then, there may be a parenthetical grouping we'd want to do. Prolog will use the parentheses so we can't just say, `trans((a ^ b)).` since it will look just like `trans(a ^ b).` to Prolog. But the translator can output parentheses (at the risk of being a little over-parenthesized):

```
trans(P) :- atom(P), write(P).

trans(P ^ Q) :-
    write('('), trans(P), write(' and '), trans(Q), write(')').
trans(P v Q) :-
    write('('), trans(P), write(' or '), trans(Q), write(')').
trans(~P) :-
    write('not '), trans(P).
trans(P => Q) :-
    write('('), write('if '), trans(P), write(' then '), trans(Q), write(')').
trans(P <=> Q) :-
    write('('), trans(P), write(' if and only if '), trans(Q), write(')').
```

And then you get:

```
| ?- trans(a ^ b <=> c v d).
((a and b) if and only if (c or d))

yes
| ?-
```

Prolog will group them (and then they'll be properly parenthesized) per the operator precedences you set in the `op/3` directives.